# Extension of an involution on $G$ to an involution on $G_\mathbb{C}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, involutions

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and  $ \sigma :G \rightarrow G $ be an involution on $G$. Let $G^\sigma :=\lbrace g \in G, \sigma(g)=g \rbrace$.

Denote by $G_\mathbb{C}$ the complexification of $G$. Does there exist an involution $\tilde{\sigma}$ on $G_\mathbb{C}$ which coïncides with $\sigma$ on $G$ and such that ${(G^{\sigma})}_\mathbb{C} = {(G_\mathbb{C})}^\tilde{\sigma}$ ?

My though was to define $\tilde{\sigma}$ to be $\sigma$ on G and to be the identity on  the complement of $G$ on $G_\mathbb{C}$, but don't see whether this imply the ${(G^{\sigma})}_\mathbb{C} = {(G_\mathbb{C})}^\tilde{\sigma}$ or not, any help please!

Comment: What is "the complement of $G$ on $G_\mathbb C$"? If you mean set-theoretic complement, then the proposed map quite likely is not even a homomorphism. (Which I assume it should be; maybe clarify exactly what kind of "involution" you want.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes by " the complement of $G$ on $G_\mathbb{C}$ " I just mean set-theoretic complement.

Comment: Actually this question came to me while reading the paper called " Matsuki correspondence for sheaves", where the authors use the terminology of involution without explaining what it is exactly, So I'll assume it is a map  which is equal to its inverse ( Not sure whether it is a homomorphism of Lie groups or not !)

Comment: I would naturally assume it has to be a Lie group morphism. Otherwise $G^\sigma$ might not even be a subgroup.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg,  I agree !

Comment: Cross-Posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425282/extension-of-an-involution-on-g-to-an-involution-on-g-mathbbc?noredirect=1#comment1093131_425282